# "Compiling php" as in making it portable

Tags: php, portable-applications

I'm not intrested in compiling for performance but in being able to "compile" a php script in order to carry it on a usb stick or portable hard drive.

I think that there may be two way:

1. Portable Apache
2. Portable command line php

I undersand that some package such as xampp and so on exists, as well as using the php bin files but I was wondering if something more user friendly exists, I mean something that I can just double click, open a browser and use.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is only interpreted. XAMPP merely sets up a mock environment with an apache server, a database, and the PHP engine. Unfortunately, XAMPP is about as fast and portable you're going to get in terms of being able to fire up a PHP app.

If you figure out a way to do it the way you're looking to - message me - I'll pay for it...

Comment: Well, there are PHP compilers. Thus I wouldn't say that it's merely interpreted ;)

Comment: There aren't any PHP compilers out there for general use - and there are no JIT compilers, period. This person is looking for a viable solution - not toys.

Answer (score 2):

searching the web gives me this

- [PCC](http://code.roadsend.com/pcc/)

and this

- [PHC](http://baheyeldin.com/technology/drupal/parrot-virtual-machine-pint-plumhead-phc-compiler-and-drupal.html)

Two native PHP compiler i found.

Comment: But as always, compiling an interpreted language that is supposed to run on a server is always a pretty much offshore.

Comment: The top link looks like they might be on to something if you're on Linux - the bottom one looks like the project is in process...

Comment: just a quick search on google for "php native compiler" ;-) no guarantee or any experience in that manner ;-)

Comment: Furthermore there is HipHop from Facebook ;)

Comment: funny here in their blog about HipHop they even refere to PPC and PHC http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358. but indeet HipHop could be an alternative too.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.4+ has a built-in webserver...  I was able to simple copy my php executable into a random folder and...

`# ~/someDir/php -S localhost:7676 -t ~/docRoot` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
PHP 5.4.0RC3 Development Server started at Tue Jan  3 15:57:33 2012
Listening on localhost:7676
Document root is /Users/localadmin/docRoot
Press Ctrl-C to quit.`
```

Browse to http://localhost:7676 and you're good to go.

If you want even more portability, you can delve into the world of recompiling PHP with a build command such as `./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-all`